# Drupal 8 error InvalidArgumentException

Tags: drupal-8

i got this with drush :

```
InvalidArgumentException: Field field_date is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 472 of 

C:\wamp\www\inf\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase.php
```

And i don't find solutions to resolve this :/
Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `domain.com/update.php` and see if it helps

if this does not solve your problem I would suggest you go to `admin/config/development/logging` and enable backtrace and reproduce the error again and look for (or post) a bug in the first module of the backtrace